# No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate.

I want to use the OpenSessionInViewFilter to allow lazy loading to work properly in the view layer.

The OpenSessionInViewFilter requires a root application context so i added a ContextLoaderListener and moved my non view related configuration files to it from the DispatcherServlet.

The app-config.xml config file contains the datasource related beans.

When i load the app-config.xml using the ContextLoaderListener instead of DispatcherServlet, i get the error message

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/XXXX/app/jobs] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
```

UPDATE: fixed this error by adding a component-scan to mvc-config.xml

but now i get

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

My understanding is that DispatcherServlet inherits beans from the root context, so moving definitions from the servlet to the root context should make no difference.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <filter>
  <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
   <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
   <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
   /WEB-INF/spring/other-config.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>

 <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml
   </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!-- Maps all /app requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

 <!--
  Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to
  configure as beans
 -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app" />

 <!-- SQL Server -->
 <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x/XXX" />
  <property name="username" value="XXX" />
  <property name="password" value="XXX" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
  <property name="configLocation">
   <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
  </property>
  <property name="configurationClass">
   <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven />

 <bean name="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**mvc-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Configures support for @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app" />

 <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
   <list>
    <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I added a <context:component-scan base-package="au.com.appliancesonline" /> to the mvc-config.xml and it fixed the mapping problem.

Comment: public int getAllCount() {
  return (Integer) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(Job.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

 }

Comment: The service method that calls it is marked as Transactional

Comment: Although i do not use OpenSessionInView pattern, your code seems right. I advice you to turn the log on and see if your service method is registered as Transactional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible problem I can see here is that `openSessionInViewFilter` is mapped after `UrlRewriteFilter`. `UrlRewriteFilter` performs `RequestDispatcher.forward()`, therefore all filters mapped after it should have `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`:

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Adding the <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> worked.  Also, switching the OpenSessionInViewFilter and the UrlRewriteFilter made it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<tx:annotation-driven />` only covers the local context in which it is defined.  In this case, it will cover the beans in app-config.xml, since that's the only place I see it in your configuration.

Depending on where your transactions are defined (and based on your error I'm assuming they're defined in beans within the mvc-config.xml context), this could result in @Transactional classes or methods which aren't wired with Spring's transaction management.

My guess is you need to add `<tx:annotation-driven />` to your mvc-config.xml.

The following is from the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html):

> `<tx:annotation-driven/>` only looks for
>   `@Transactional` on beans in the same
>   application context it is defined in.
>   This means that, if you put
>   `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in a
>   `WebApplicationContext` for a
>   `DispatcherServlet`, it only checks for
>   `@Transactional` beans in your
>   controllers, and not your services.
>   [See Section 15.2, “The
>   DispatcherServlet”](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) for more
>   information.